# Python socket.recv() data into Pandas DataFrame DF: is there a better workflow?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sockets, xlwings

Python script connects (in localhost) to a trading software via 'socket' and using a socket.recv() call , I receive all the requested price-feed information (time, symbol, bid, ask, last, last quantity, volume...etc) .

Now, I want to analyze and manipulate these records, so I append them into one global Pandas Dataframe called 'priceAll' and then use it on separate functions to create outputs filtering, summing, grouping-by ...etc, and lastly outputting real-time those 'filtered' outputs to an excel sheet using Xlwings via COM

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import socket
import xlwings as xw
...

priceAll= pd.DataFrame()

def second_func(priceAll_local):
    #blabla...
    #groupy-by , sum, isin.... etc
    ...
    xw.Book(file_path).sheets['sheet1'].range('A1').value = filtered_DF 
    
    
def readSocket():
    ...
    ...
    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect(('localhost', 10001))
    print ("> Socket Connected >")

    cmd = (cmd_syntax).encode() 
    mysock.send(cmd) #sending CMD request 
    
    while True:
        msg = mysock.recv(16384)
        msg_stringa=str(msg,'utf-8')
        read_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(msg_stringa) , sep=";", error_bad_lines=False, 
                        index_col=None, header=None, 
                        engine='c', names=range(33),
                        decimal = '.')

        #if there are new prices 
        if (len(priceDF) > 0):
            priceAll = priceAll.append(priceDF, ignore_index=True).copy()
            priceAll.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, keep='last')
            priceAll.dropna(how='any',inplace=True) 
            
            second_func(priceAll)
            third_func(priceAll)
            ....
            last_func(priceAll)
        
        #it drops rows older than 10 minutes
        priceAll = priceAll[(now - priceAll['time']).astype('timedelta64[s]') < 600 ].copy() 
        ...
        ...
        #blabla...
```

I am very aware Pandas DFs are not meant to be used as real-time boxes in which to append continuous data but:

- Size of 'priceAll' gets to 3000-4000 rows by 8 columns max
- Process time (excluding receiving data from socket) is about 200-300ms per cycle, not too bad.
- Pandas DF are handy to manipulate and very powerful

**MY QUESTION**: is there a better workflow for my tasks, preferably Python-based ? both to collect tabular data as an alternative to Pandas DFs (socket is a must-do), and , is there a better way to output it **real-time** as an alternative to Excel via Xlwings?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to argue with code that works.  Do you actually need `pandas` to process this data?  If so, then there's probably not a much better solution.

Comment: Tim, thank you for your feedback. Yes indeed `pandas` is really handy and I need it for easy group-by , sum , average of values . I am not familiar with any other different environment/library . Thanks

Comment: Well, I'll share my thinking, although it may not apply to you.  I see too many people going straight from files into pandas, and then wasting gobs of time trying to write complicated queries and updates on their DataFrames, when in fact it would have been much easier to read the data into plain lists, do some simple manipulation, and THEN go into pandas for analysis, where it is the king.  That's all I'm trying to point out.